# BITMAPFILEHEADER and BITMAPINFOHEADER are not recognized

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-c++-2012

I have a Win32 built Visual Studio 2012 built vcxproj project. The code has a definition of a bitmap header structure union in the header. The union definition is set int he header of the application. The problem is the header cannot recognize the BITMAPFILEHEADER and BITMAPINFOHEADER. I added #include WinGDI.h and Windows.h but it is still not recognized.

```
union MY_BITMAP
{
    struct BITMAPFILEHEADER bmf;
    struct BITMAPINFOHEADER  bmi;
};
```

I have tried to change the C/C++ pre-processor definition and added the following code but it still does not work

```
_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601
```

What settings do I need to make the compiler aware of the definition?

PS. As per @RetiredNinja's comment The error I received is C2079 for both bmf and bmi.

Comment: You included Windows.h?  Have you tried removing `struct` in front of the declarations.

Comment: @RetiredNinja yes I did include that too. Updating the question.

Comment: You should add the exact compile errors you're seeing to the question.  It compiles fine for me without struct.  Not sure if you're compiling C or C++ code since you didn't specify or tag the question appropriately.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I only get C2079: for both 'MY_BITMAP::bmf' and  'MY_BITMAP::bmi'. I noticed something, when I removed the keyword "struct" in the union definition, the error is gone. Is there a difference in the syntax of adding struct with no struct in union definition?